# firefox pop-up blocker doesn't work

Tags: firefox, popups

I'm downloading something from mediafire.com. but there's lots of pop-ups everytime I click on the download button. Is there a firefox extension which blocks pop-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type of pop-ups mediafire displays, but you could try the [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/) Add-on together with the [Adblock Plus Pop-up Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/83098/).